# SQL Query to chunk data in bunch of 5 for each group

Tags: sql

```
col1, col2
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
2,1
2,2
2,3
2,4
2,5
2,6
```

Expected Output:

```
col1, col2, chunk_no
1,1 ,1
1,2 ,1
1,3 ,1
1,4 ,1
1,5 ,1
1,6 ,2
1,7 ,2
2,1 ,3
2,2 ,3
2,3 ,3
2,4 ,3
2,5 ,3
2,6 ,5
```

so it is bunch of 5 based on grouping.
Group 1 has 7 records so it will have chunk 1 (for first 5) and 2(for last 2 rows).
when new group will come then chunk number will increase by 1.

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  And what happened to chunk "4"?

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes more sense if chunk 5 should really be 4.

You want to increment the "chunk" for every fifth record within `col1` and when `col1` changes.  This suggests a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*, sum(flag) over (order by col1, col2) as chunk_num
from (select t.*,
             (case when row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) % 5 = 1
                   then 1
                   else 0
              end) as flag
      from t
     ) t;
```